# What are these scripts that are loading in Chrome when I press F12? (ophan, jquery)

Tags: javascript, security, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When I press F12 in Chrome on my own web site, I see these scripts in the network tab. I don't include them, they are not in the HTML source, and I don't know where they come from.

[image: Imgur]

The URLs are

```
http://j.ophan.co.uk/ophan.r2.js.map
https://d1e1g6hlwfi0h5.cloudfront.net/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-2.0.3.min.map
```

I can't find anything in Google about 'ophan'.

I do use Google Analytics and New Relic. I also use AdBlock Plus, Awesome Screenshot Capture, and Google Voice extensions.

When I reload the page, they are gone. They only show up when I open F12, and only for my site, `https://tyger.ac/users/48`. I disabled all my extensions, and it still happens. It does NOT happen in a private browser session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are [source map files](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/) and they are only loaded when the dev console is open. Basically the file maps minified names like `function a() {}` to `function realFunctionName() {}` so that debugging minified code is easier.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's just script related with Adblock Plus. [Example Script](https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/easyprivacy.txt)

Comment: I disabled all extensions, and it still happens. Plus, I don't have ads on my site.

Comment: Peculiar, I closed the tab and opened in a fresh tab and it's not doing it any more.